# How is the training accuracy in Keras determined for every epoch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am training a model in Keras with as follows:

```
model.fit(Xtrn, ytrn batch_size=16, epochs=50, verbose=1, shuffle=True,
          callbacks=[model_checkpoint], validation_data=(Xval, yval))
```

The fitting output looks as follows:

[image]

As shown in the `model.fit` I have a batch size of 16 and a total of `8000` training samples as shown in the output. So from my understanding, training takes place every `16` batches. Which also means training is ran `500` times for a single epoch (i.e., `8000/16 =500)`

So let's take the training accuracy printed in the output for Epoch 1/50, which in this case is `0.9381`. I would like to know how is this training accuracy of `0.9381` derived.

Is it the:

1. Is the ***mean*** training accuracy, taken as the average from the `500` times training, performed for every batch?

OR,

2. Is it the best (or ***max***) training accuracy from out of the `500` instances the training procedure is run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the `BaseLogger` in `Keras` where they're computing a running mean.
For each epoch the accuracy is the average of all the batches seen before in that epoch.

```
class BaseLogger(Callback):
    """Callback that accumulates epoch averages of metrics.

    This callback is automatically applied to every Keras model.
    """

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.seen = 0
        self.totals = {}

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        batch_size = logs.get('size', 0)
        self.seen += batch_size

        for k, v in logs.items():
            if k in self.totals:
                self.totals[k] += v * batch_size
            else:
                self.totals[k] = v * batch_size

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if logs is not None:
            for k in self.params['metrics']:
                if k in self.totals:
                    # Make value available to next callbacks.
                    logs[k] = self.totals[k] / self.seen
```

Comment: so the training accuracy is based on the mean of all batches. thank you for confirming, I would also like to find out if the mean of the validation accuracy is also done for all batches of the validation data. Please see edit to my post with `ONE MORE QUESTION`