# How is the validation accuracy in Keras determined for every epoch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

This is in relation to a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831242/how-is-the-training-accuracy-in-keras-determined-for-every-epoch).

Is the validation data evaluated on the model which gives the `0.9381` training accuracy or is it based on also splitting the validation data across the `500` steps per epoch, then taking the mean validation accuracy across all steps ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Are you asking the how validation loss is calculated during an epoch or are you asking which model is taken for final validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your training accuracy is evaluated after every batch. 
The validation accuracy is calculated at the end of the Epoch.

If you want to test it, you can create a custom callback (https://keras.io/callbacks/). There is a method *on_batch_end* used for training accuracy and *on_epoch_end* used for the validation datas. If you save within the callback the accuracy and plot it, you will see the evolution.

You can see below, for example, the evolution of accuracy of 4 RNN cells after every batch on 1 Epoch. As the result was extremely noisy, I've added a sliding average. The star is the validation score at the end of the Epoch.

[image]