# Understanding metrics computation in Keras

Tags: keras

I have tried to implement a true positive metric in Keras :

```py
def TP(y_true, y_pred):
    estimated = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    truth = K.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    TP = K.sum(truth * estimated)
    return TP
```

based on my last layer output shape : *(batch, 2)*.
The function has been tested with numpy argmax equivalent and works well.

I use a cross_entropy loss function and each epochs it gives me the metric value. But how this value could be a **decimal number ?**  What am I doing wrong ? Thanks !

**Edited** : here is a sample code for the Keras model :

```py
def TP(y_true, y_pred):
    estimated = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    truth = K.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    TP = K.sum(truth * estimated)
    return TP

epochs = 10
batch_size = 2

model = Sequential([
        Dense(32, input_shape=(4,)),
        Activation('relu'),
        Dense(2),
        Activation('softmax'),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', TP])

model.summary()

train = np.array([[17,0,1,0],[17,0,1,0],[17,0,1,0],[17,0,1,0],[17,0,1,0], [2,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1]])
labels = np.array([ [1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0], [0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1] ])

model.fit(train, labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)
```

And here a test showing the *TP* function seems to work

```py
def npTP(y_true, y_pred):
    estimated = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    truth = np.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    TP = np.sum(truth * estimated)
    return TP

y_true = np.array([ [1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0], [0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1] ])
y_pred = np.array([ [0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1], [0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]])
print("np check : ")
print(npTP(y_true, y_pred))
```

Running this code gives the following output :

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                160       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 66        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 226
Trainable params: 226
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.3934 - acc: 0.6000 - TP: 0.2000
Epoch 2/10                           ^^^^^^^^^^ here are the decimal values
 - 0s - loss: 0.3736 - acc: 0.6000 - TP: 0.2000
Epoch 3/10                           ^^^^^^^^^^
 - 0s - loss: 0.3562 - acc: 0.6000 - TP: 0.2000
Epoch 4/10                           ^^^^^^^^^^
 - 0s - loss: 0.3416 - acc: 0.7000 - TP: 0.4000
Epoch 5/10                           ^^^^^^^^^^
 - 0s - loss: 0.3240 - acc: 1.0000 - TP: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.3118 - acc: 1.0000 - TP: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.2960 - acc: 1.0000 - TP: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.2806 - acc: 1.0000 - TP: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.2656 - acc: 1.0000 - TP: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.2535 - acc: 1.0000 - TP: 1.0000

np check : 
5
```

Thanks !

Comment: Please notice that posting questions is not a fire-and-forget thing, and the best moment to post is **not** before going away for lunch/coffee/whatever. The first 20-30 mins are of great importance if you want to get your question answered, and you are expected to be available to answer to comments & clarification requests; from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "*After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it*".

Comment: So, you have indeed 5 TP's (the last 5 elements of your `y_pred` & `y_true`); what exactly is the issue here and what is this "decimal" you refer to?

Comment: The 5 TP's are when I use the numpy function. With the Keras metric included in the `fit` training, the first 4 epochs gives 0.2 and 0.4 as number of true positives. I don't get why.

Comment: This is a *running average* between batches & epochs, so it can take decimal values indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831242/how-is-the-training-accuracy-in-keras-determined-for-every-epoch

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As desertnaut pointed out, answer is explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831242/how-is-the-training-accuracy-in-keras-determined-for-every-epoch).

### Keras is doing a *running average* between batches & epochs.

Here with `batch_size=2` and 10 samples, each epoch runs 5 trainings (`10/2=5`).

To understand output metric of epoch 1, the total number of `TP` after the 5 trainings had to be 1, so the metric gives `1/5 = 0.2`. Epoch 4 had 2 TP's in the 5 trainings giving `2/5 = 0.4` in the metric.